# BibLaTeX \DeclareCiteCommand: How to check shorthand and citeseen and choose <wrapper> accordingly?

Tags: biblatex, citing

This question is closely related to [Biblatex: Autocite dependent on shorthand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211266/biblatex-autocite-dependent-on-shorthand) but since that question asks about `autocite`, I decided to open a new question.

I am trying to to declare a citation command `\mycite`, which behaves like `\footcite` for bib-entries without a `shorthand` field *and* for bib-entries with `shorthand` field when they are cited for the first time. If a bib-entry with `shorthand` field is cited for the second time `\mycite` should behave like `\parencite`

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{Book1, author={Author 1}, title={Title 1}, shorthand={Shorthand1}}
    @book{Book2, author={Author 2}, title={Title 2}}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=verbose,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\mycite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}

\begin{document}
Citing an entry with defined shorthand field for the first time \mycite{Book1}.

Citing an entry with undefined shorthand field \mycite{Book2}.

Citing an entry with defined shorthand field for the second time \mycite{Book1}.
\end{document}
```

This gives the following output:

[image]
[image]

I would like `\mycite` to output instead:

[image]
[image]

Sadly the following declaration of `\mycite` does not work:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\mycite}[\iffieldundef{shorthand}\mkbibfootnote\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}
```

So what I tried instead, was to repurpose the `<precode>` and `<postcode>` fields by copy pasting the definitions of `\mkbibparens` and others, which seems to work for simple tasks like using square or rounded brackets depending on the shorthand field:

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\mycite}[]
  {\iffieldundef{shorthand}{%
    \begingroup
    \blx@blxinit
    \blx@setsfcodes
    \bibopenparen
    \usebibmacro{prenote}}{%
    \begingroup
    \blx@blxinit
    \blx@setsfcodes
    \bibopenbracket
    \usebibmacro{prenote}}%
   }
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\iffieldundef{shorthand}{%
    \usebibmacro{cite:postnote}%
    \bibcloseparen%
    \endgroup}{%
    \usebibmacro{cite:postnote}%
    \bibclosebracket%
    \endgroup}
  }
\makeatother
```

This might well be a very bad and ugly hack. And I have no idea how to do this with the `\mkbibfootnote` wrapper, which is more complex then the ones for `\mkbibparens` or `\mkbibbrackets`.

I would like to note, that the most important thing for me here is, to have a cite command which behaves like `\footcite` for entries without `shorthand` field and which behaves like `\parencite` for entries with `shorthand` field.

Comment: What would you want to happen if you were to cite two works that would trigger different behaviour as in `\cite{foo,bar}` where `foo` does have a shorthand and `bar` does not? If you only ever cite one work at a time a workaround is very easy (just move `\ifciteseen` and `\mkbibfootnote` into the loopcode), if not one would probably have to resort to more trickery.

Comment: The problem I have with what you are aiming at is that it makes it really hard for readers to track citations properly: Sometimes they will appear in the footnote, sometimes in the body. Especially if a shorthand is introduced a reader will have read the footnote in order to understand a subsequent shorthand in the text, so no footnote skipping would be allowed.

Comment: I can come up with a not that ugly solution, which unfortunately does only work if you restrict yourself to only citing one work per `\mycite`. Give me a shout if you would like to see that. Incidentally, the answer has pretty much the form of Guido's answer in the linked question.

Comment: @moewe Thank you for your comments and suggestions. You have good points there. When citing multiple entries the best solution for me would be to have them all in a footnote. But since I rarely do that, it would be sufficient to just use `\footcite` in these cases, I guess. Also your point about readability is sound. As I briefly mentioned, having the first citation of a bib-entry with shorthand field in a footnote is not all that important to me, but it would still be nice to know, how to do that. If you could show me your solution for citing one work at a time, that would really help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution will work smoothly if you only ever cite one work per `\mycite`.
This is because we had to move all the code into the loopcode of the citation command which is executed for every key cited.
As we need to access information about the entry (i.e. does it have a `shorthand` field?) which is only available in the loopcode (and to a certain degree in the pre and postcodes?), it was necessary to make this adjustment.

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\mycite}[\unspace]
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \ifboolexpr{not test {\iffieldundef{shorthand}} and test {\ifciteseen}}%
     {\space\mkbibparens{\usebibmacro{prenote}\printfield{shorthand}\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}}
     {\mkbibfootnote{\usebibmacro{prenote}\usebibmacro{cite}\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {}
```

The idea is straightforward, we check if we have an entry with a `shorthand` that was already cited, if so we default to a `\parencite` with the shorthand; otherwise we do a normal cite in the footnote.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{Book1, author={Author 1}, title={Title 1}, shorthand={Shorthand1}}
    @book{Book2, author={Author 2}, title={Title 2}}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[style=verbose,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\mycite}[\unspace]
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \ifboolexpr{not test {\iffieldundef{shorthand}} and test {\ifciteseen}}%
     {\space\mkbibparens{\usebibmacro{prenote}\printfield{shorthand}\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}}
     {\mkbibfootnote{\usebibmacro{prenote}\usebibmacro{cite}\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {}

\begin{document}
Citing an entry with defined shorthand field for the first time\mycite[Cf.][1]{Book1}.

Citing an entry with undefined shorthand field \mycite[2]{Book2}.

Citing an entry with defined shorthand field for the second time\mycite[4]{Book1}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you moewe! I changed it a little to `\mkbibparens{\iffieldundef{prenote}{}{\printfield{prenote} }\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}\iffieldundef{postnote}{}{ \printfield{postnote}}}` Maybe you should consider to post your answer as an example to the question [Biblatex: Autocite dependent on shorthand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211266/biblatex-autocite-dependent-on-shorthand) since my question now seems kind of a replicate to that one and you could help @Denis with it. Of course I could add a link to this post there, if you wish. Anyway: Thank you!

Comment: @Wamseln Was there anything that prompted you to do that change? I could not find any undesirable behaviour with my code and I think that internally the macros pretty much do what you want (plus/minus setting an appropriate separator which can be controlled via `\postnotedelim` and `\prenotedelim`). I don't think it is necessary to add this answer to the other question, Guido's answer pretty much covers it and the question is already linked to so people can see they are related.

Comment: Thanks again moewe. You are right. The additional `\iffieldundef`'s are not necessary.  But I use `\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}` instead of `\printfield{shorthand}` because I made some changes to the bibmacro `{cite:shorthand}` and I want these changes to take effect. So now I use: `\mkbibparens{\usebibmacro{prenote}\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}`

Comment: Sorry. I now tested with my real document and not with the MWE and remembered again, why I did use the additional `\iffieldundef`'s: It's a quick and dirty hack in order to prevent any kind of special formatting for articles. Without the additional `\iffieldundef`'s I get an additional _here: _ in front of the page number when citing a shorthand entry, which I do not want. To clarify: With your unchanged MWE I would get: **Shorthand1, here: p. 12**. With my hackish change I get: **Shorthand1, p.12** I didn't want to take the time, figuring out how to do this the proper way.

Comment: I am sorry for my chaotic explanations and for using three comments instead of just one. But to clarify further: I wanted to suppress special formatting like _Shorthand1, here: p. 12_ for articles. Therefore I used `\printfield` instead of `\usebibmacro`. But the `\printfield` printed undesired spaces when empty, so I added `\iffieldundef` in order to prevent the spaces, when the field was empty.

Comment: @Wamseln Mhhh, I cannot reproduce any "here" with `@article`s, but then I don't know exactly what you are doing. (My only guess is that it might have to do with the `citepages` option: `citepages=separate` does some fancy things to the postnote macro.) If it works for you it is fine though I suppose, if you are interested in an investigation, you might ask a new question.